# Automatic installation of run-time libraries with WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.5, msvcrt

When my file set includes DLLs with one ore more dependencies to the C++ run-time DLLs I need to install the file from VCRedist.exe. This can be difficult, since each DLL is dependent on a specific version of the C++ run-time.

- How do I add automatically the run-time redistributables to my installer?
- How do I handle DLLs that require different versions of the C++ run-time in the WinSxS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither heat nor Votive does support the requested feature. The run-time DLLs must be added manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the latest version (highest) version required by your libraries and a policy file that redirects older versions to the new version.

You can do both with merge modules installed with Visual Studio. They're usually located in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Merge Modules`. See [`MergeRef`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_mergeref.htm) element and an example [how to install Visual C++ redistributable with your installer](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/install_vcredist.htm). You will also need to add a policy merge module to your install.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple make sure the latest vcredist is installed, it automatically includes support for older versions.

I think the easiest it to use [bootstrapper](http://wix.mindcapers.com/wiki/Bootstrapper) to install the runtime before your installer runs. You might need to create your own package, but it is easy to use [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg) for this.

In the product.xml you can add an installation check to make sure it is not installed twice, for example:

```
  <InstallChecks>
    <MsiProductCheck Property="VCRedistInstalled" Product="{1F1C2DFC-2D24-3E06-BCB8-725134ADF989}"/>
  </InstallChecks>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203195/how-to-detect-vc-2008-redistributable/2880309#2880309) for other GUIDs.

Comment: There is no support from 'heat' or Votive to detect this? I should manage the .wxs files after detection, but an initial creation of a fragment would be appreciated.

Comment: A bootstrapper is not part of wix, so you can't use heat for this. See for example `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\*` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\BootStrapper\Packages\*` for existing files. Use BMG to create such a file.

Comment: I don't necessarely need a bootstrapper. In the WiX.CHM section "How To: Install the Visual C++ Redistributable with your installer" you find how to include the merge module. This is part of WiX and I seek for a way to get this more convenient and less error prone.

Comment: You can use a merge module too, as suggested by Alexey Ivanov. But I stopped using that because I had too often warnings in wix caused by the merge modules. However, the merge modules were working fine.