# Detect VC++ Redistributable ATL SP1 (Before Setup begins)

Tags: wix, wix3.5, redistributable

My project depends upon "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package ATL Security Update", I want to put a check at the beginning of the setup to display a condition error if the package is not installed..

I checked this question: [How to detect VC++ 2008 redistributable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203195/how-to-detect-vc-2008-redistributable)? I cannot find the registry entry provided for visual C++ 2005 SP1 ATL Security Update runtime files (After installing the redistributable manually)..

What am I doing wrong here? And is there a better to detect the redistributable package?

Thanks,

Comment: You can try to run filesystem / registry monitor software while installing that update, and it will trace all the places it writes to.

Comment: You can include ATL SP1 merge modules in your setup package instead of detecting it. This way your package will be complete, and it will install successful in either case: whether ATL SP1 is installed or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the same answer:

Installed OR (HASVCPP200564)

There are different registry guids for 32/64 bit, the above is 64 bit.

Cheers,

Comment: How/where is this property defined?