# How to determine if the 32-bit Visual Studio 2013 redistributable is installed on a user's machine reliably via the Registry?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, registry, visual-studio-2013, redistributable

I am using [DeployMaster](http://www.deploymaster.com/) to build an installer for a 32-bit Windows application written in C++ using Qt.

The executable depends on the Visual Studio 2013 redistributable - i.e., the [32-bit Visual Studio 2013 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) must be installed by the end user, prior to running this application.

I have googled, and looked at other StackOverflow questions.  In particular, [this link provides the exact Registry key to check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/657693/368896), but for the case of VS 2008.

I need VS 2013, not VS 2008.

However, ideally it will be a reliable registry check - not a programmatic solution - because I can easily check a registry key with a DeployMaster installer.  (If the system is determined to not have the redistributable installed, it's also easy to have the DeployMaster installer kick off the installer.)

Does anybody know a reliable method, preferably using a Registry key, that allows to make it possible to determine if the 32-bit VS 2013 redistributable is installed on an end-user's machine?

Comment: Might work to figure this out yourself: run SysInternal's ProcMon on a machine (can be virtual) that doesn't have the redist installed yet and start the installation. That will reveal any registry keys it creates. Pick a suitable one (like those from HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products) and you're done..

Comment: I *think* the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\RuntimeMinimum` (checking for `Install = 1`), but I would like confirmation that this or any answer is *reliable*.  Good thought (though why should a programmer be forced to do that level of work just to see if a basic Microsoft runtime system is installed?  That is another failure on Microsoft's part).

Comment: yes that key is used as well probably - don't really agree with the pointing finger though.. In the end it's always somebody's fault, and I might as well eg claim it's DeployMaster's fault as they make you figure this out yourself :P since eg InstallShield has this functionality built-in for VC redists IIRC

Comment: @stijn InstallShield - another $1000 product that inspires you to "pay" for functionality to support another company's functionality that you must also pay for that isn't adequate.  Good for them, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key you need is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\RuntimeMinimum`.

Answer (score 12):

I'm using these reg keys:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\VC\Runtimes\x86` `Installed`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\VC\Runtimes\x64` `Installed`

I've confirmed that they appear only after the redist is installed, and they more closely match the ones for previous versions. e.g. VC++ 2010 is:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86` `Installed`
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x64` `Installed`

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is looking at this, but is using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) to deploy their program.

You check:

```
ReadRegDword $0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vc\Servicing\12.0\RuntimeMinimum" "Install"
```

If `$0` equals `1`, then it is installed. If not, it isn't.

Comment: This key is not alwayse created and is not a trustworthy indicator.

Answer (score 1):

I found it here:

```
32bit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{13A4EE12-23EA-3371-91EE-EFB36DDFFF3E}
or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{13A4EE12-23EA-3371-91EE-EFB36DDFFF3E}

64bit
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{A749D8E6-B613-3BE3-8F5F-045C84EBA29B}
```

This is probably better than the devdiv keys, as its the Windows key used to uninstall the msi, if its been installed. Now I just wish Microsoft's devdiv could talk to the Windows team so we can have a canonical place to detect this stuff, and a canonical name for Redistributable. Hint Microsoft, it ain't called 'minimum runtime'

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, 32 bit version (12.0.40664), the key is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{8122DAB1-ED4D-3676-BB0A-CA368196543E}
```