# How to fail Octopus deploy if missing vc2013 Redistributable Packages are missing

Tags: octopus-deploy

Ho can I check if the C++ redistributable packages for visual studio 2013 is installed and fail if not.

I need to check if the x64 and x86 version is installed.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Powershell Scripts in Octopus Deploy](http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/PowerShell+scripts)

> Tentacle examines the exit code of PowerShell.exe to determine whether
>   the script failed. If the exit code is zero, Tentacle assumes the
>   script ran successfully. If the exit code is non-zero, then Tentacle
>   assumes the script failed.

So, write a PowerShell script that returns non-zero exit code if what you're looking for isn't installed.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206314/detect-if-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2012-is-installed) gives you the registry keys you're looking for, for the 2012 version. Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14878248/270392). You might just need to find what the keys are (if different) for the 2013.

Hopefully this gives you a start in the right direction though at least.

Comment: Thanks I will try and use the registry to check the installed version.
[This question/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702199/how-to-determine-if-the-32-bit-visual-studio-2013-redistributable-is-installed-o) is also useful